# Loop div headings and retrieve li tags for every heading tag

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a webpage that employs JS objects.

I am using Selenium in a Python environment; I use selenium to load what I want, that being the "VIEW SELECT TV PACKAGE DETAILS" text which launches a modal container.

[image]

In this container, there are package headings, with channels underneath them. I am trying to iterate over each heading, and grab the channel names within each.

This is the [webpage](https://www.rogers.com/consumer/tv#/packages)

Here is my code which will help you navigate to the container I am trying to scrape:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.rogers.com/consumer/tv#/packages"

#create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get(url)

#change the province to Ontario
province_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("dropdown-toggle")
province_button.click() #clicks dropdown
province_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Ontario")
province_button.click() #clicks dropdown

#visit TV portal page, re-init url again
driver.get(url)


#####BEGIN SCRAPING PACKAGE INFO#####

#open Select Package window 
package_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Package-details")
package_button.click() #clicks dropdown

package_data = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Package-channels")
```

the `package_data` var returns all my headings and channel names; but not indication of which strings were headings and which were channels. I know I could write some complex regex to do the trick but I'm hoping for a dynamic approach. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

******EDITED*******

Per comments below, below is code that takes WebElements into a variable instead of outputting to console:

```
select_package_data = [] 

headingsCount = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal- 
content']//*[contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding')]"))

for index in range(headingsCount):
    head = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']//* 
    [contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding')] 
    [index]".replace('index',str(index+1)))

    select_package_data.append(head.text)

    channelsPerheading = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div[@class='modal- 
    content']//ul[@ng-if='vm.channels'])[index]/li[not 
    (contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng- 
    binding'))]".replace('index',str(index+1)))

    temp_list=[]

for channel in channelsPerheading:
    temp_list.append(channel.text.encode('utf-8'))
select_package_data.insert((index+1), temp_list[:])`
```

*********EDITED V2 PER COMMENTS:*********

Final code required adding a parenthesis in the xpath method; I believe this is due to the `[index]` appended to the end of the actual xpath when assigning it to a variable:

```
#get the count of headings in the modal contaier
headingsCount = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal- 
content']//*[contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding')]"))

#use this count as an iterator
for index in range(headingsCount):

#get the first heading - we use replace method bc xpath is not zero-indexed
head = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='modal-content']//* 
[contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding')]) 
[index]".replace('index',str(index+1)))

header_placeholder = head.text 
##takes heading element as text to use for dataframe row index label 

#goes to //ul tag in accordance with current index, finds all BUT the 
#headings
channelsPerheading = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div[@class='modal- 
content']//ul[@ng-if='vm.channels'])[index]/li[not 
(contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng- 
binding'))]".replace('index',str(index+1)))

temp_list=[]

for channel in channelsPerheading: #append the channels as text to a temp 
list
    temp_list.append(channel.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to fetch all the headings and channels in the modal window is by using the below xpaths. Also, below xpaths are dynamic and not hardcoded. Even if new channels or headings are added in future, these xpaths will still work.

```
headings = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']//*[contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding')]")
print('all headings: '+str(len(headings)))

channels= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']//a[contains(@class,'PackageChannelImage')]")
print('all channels: '+str(len(channels)))
```

Output:

```
all headings: 17
all channels: 243
```

You can use the below approach to fetch the channels per heading and print them.

```
headingsCount = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']//*[contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding')]"))

for index in range(headingsCount):
    print('For heading: '+ driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='modal-content']//*[contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding')])[index]".replace('index',str(index+1))).text+', Channels are:')
    channelsPerheading = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div[@class='modal-content']//ul[@ng-if='vm.channels'])[index]/li[not (contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding'))]".replace('index',str(index+1)))
    for channel in channelsPerheading:
        print(channel.text.encode('utf-8').strip())
```

I have pasted the output [here](https://gist.github.com/Kannamaraj/70a00e6fcc6e2357529e409c6c9dd537)

Comment: Thanks @Kireeti for clarifying xpath syntax for pulling `headings` and `channels`. I am trying to organize the data to denote which `channels` fall under each `heading`. For example in screenshot above: the **Family** heading contains **5 channels**; those being 2 Treehouse and 3 YTV.  Is there an iterative approach to this problem i.e. for every heading, return the channel tags beneath it ?

Comment: Thanks @KireetiAnnamaraj, the xpath syntax and add'l methods successfully prints this to console. I've adapted your code to output the text to a list data structure, however `find_element_by_xpath` for the headings, returns a `NoSuchElementException` for any index higher than 1.  This is **not** the case when printing to console

Comment: I have edited my OP above with the code I am using - any feedback is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi @MarkSamuel, you need to use xpath as this way: `(//div[@class='modal-content']//*[contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding')]) [index]`. for heading. Could you give it a try?

Comment: Thanks Kireeti - this worked, I have updated OP to show final code. It is strange how that initial parenthesis is unneeded in this code block: `headingsCount = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']//*[contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding')]"))`  
                                                versus this code block:    `head = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='modal-content']//*[contains(@class,'Package-channels--heading ng-binding')])[index]".replace('index',str(index+1)))`

Comment: is it that when adding an index to the tail of the xpath method, requires a closing parenthesis for the actual xpath ?

Comment: Yes, enclosing the xpath in () and then we can iterate through all elements found using that xpath by using [index] where index starts from '1' unlike our programming array which starts with '0'